# How to reduce time taken by tooltipValueGetter in ag Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

```
 var ColDef = [{
        headerName: "colA",
        field: 'colA',
        rowGroup: true
      },
      {
        headerName: "colB",
        field: 'colB',
        pivot: true,
        enablePivot: true
      },
      {
        headerName: "colC",
        field: 'colC',
        rowGroup: true
      },
      {
        field: 'colD',
        aggFunc: 'last',
    tooltipValueGetter: commentTooltipValueGetter
      },
      {
        field: 'comment'
      },
      {
        field: 'colF'
      }
    ];


    function commentTooltipValueGetter(params) {
    const colB = params.colDef.pivotKeys[0];
    var model = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < model.allLeafChildren.length ; i++) {
        if (model.allLeafChildren[i].data.colB=== colB) {
          return model.allLeafChildren[i].data.comments;
                                                       }
                                             }
  }
```

For me when i hover over colD i get the comments as tooltip. but they take like 2-3 seconds to come up. Any way to reduce this time? Also my agGrid is pivot and group ag Grid not the normal one. Please take that into consideration when suggesting answers. 
I have been already using tooltipShowDelay before i asked this question, looks like sometimes its very fast and sometimes it takes couple of seconds hovering for the tooltipValueGetter to do its magic

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you are doing a lot of processing, so ideally it should take less time.

From v23.1.0, ag-grid has provided this gridOption,  `tooltipShowDelay = 0`;

> AG-2968   [Feature Request]   23.1.0  Allow configuring how long it
>   takes a tooltip to popup

From docs -

> By default, when you hover on an item, it will take 2 seconds for the
>   tooltip to be displayed. If you need to change this delay, the
>   tooltipShowDelay config should be used, which is set in milliseconds.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tooltip-component/#tooltip-show-delay

Comment: I have been already using tooltipShowDelay before i asked this question, looks like sometimes its very fast and sometimes it takes couple of seconds hovering for the tooltipValueGetter to do its magic

Comment: Oh. Can you add that to your question? Also are you using the latest version?